# Descargar archivo en Python con una conexión intermitente

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-requests

Utilizo el siguiente código para descargar archivos en Python, pero al parecer en máquinas que tienen conexión intermitente, es decir, que la conexión no es fluida se pierde la descarga o ésta se vuelve demasiado lenta.

El peso de los archivos que son descargados no sobrepasan los 20Mb.

```
import requests
import shutil

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

    return local_filename
```

¿Que faltaría para evitar ésta situación?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

¿Como podría implementar de manera correcta un re-intento si falla la descarga?

Comment: Depende del problema real, no es lo mimo perdida de conexión a que solo sea un servidor lento. Si el server soporta range request podrías descargar el archivo en fragmentos lo que te permitiría reiniciar una descarga dado el caso si falla en algún punto o incluso usar varios hilos para la descarga, https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59824/15089. Ajustar el [timeout](http://es.python-requests.org/es/latest/user/advanced.html#timeouts) de la petición puede ser de ayuda si el servidor es muy lento.

Comment: Entiendo, no hay nada que hacer si el problema es la conexión, como en este caso el problema está en el equipo cliente. ¿Como podría implementar de manera correcta un re intento?

Comment: El servidor no soporta header Range :(

Comment: Ajustar el timeout fue de gran ayuda para resolver este tema ya que la descarga está dentro de un bucle y si el servidor tarda en responder simplemente omite la operación y lo intenta en el siguiente ciclo. Muchas gracias por tu comentario @FJSevilla.